# Padding-related CryptographicException in previously working code

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a program which stores encrypted text data. Whenever new data is added, the encrypted data is loaded from file, decrypted, the new string data is appended, and finally the data is re-encrypted and saved to disk. This used to work until recently, now however I get a `CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed` when decrypting the loaded data. This is the code I use to encrypt/decrypt the data:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(string text, byte[] key) {
    byte[] encrypted;
    byte[] IV;

    using (var aes = Aes.Create()) {
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        IV = aes.IV;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
            using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {
                swEncrypt.Write(text);
            }
            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
    // return plaintext IV and encrypted text payload concatenated
    return IV.Concat(encrypted).ToArray();
} // Encrypt()

public static string Decrypt(byte[] bytes, byte[] key) {
    string plaintext = null;

    using (var aes = Aes.Create()) {
        aes.Key = key;

        // split iv and encryped cyphertext
        byte[] IV = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[bytes.Length - IV.Length];
        Array.Copy(bytes, IV, IV.Length);
        Array.Copy(bytes, IV.Length, cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);

        aes.IV = IV;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) {
            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd(); 
            // !!! EXCEPTION HAPPENS HERE !!!
        }
    }

    return plaintext;
}
```

The encrypted `byte[]` array is read/written using plain `File.ReadAllBytes` / `File.WriteAllBytes`.

I tried to change the the code to read byte by byte until an exception occurs, which gave me the decrypted text minus 16 bytes. However, only the first third contained valid text, the rest was a few garbled bytes, followed by a (equally garbled) 16 byte sequence, repeated over and over. This makes me suspect that some kind of corruption occurred during a previous save operation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, regarding to recovering the data (if possible) and pointing out problems/bugs in the encryption/decryption code (if any).

Comment: Try setting `aes.Padding`. It should be set to PKCS7 by default, but your issue stinks of incorrect padding.

Comment: What I learned from this is that I should always validate that the encrypted data are decryptable, before replacing the existing data in the database!